# Handling native threads during onPause()

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, android-ndk, android-lifecycle

So I have an android game that has some tight integration of Java and C++. Both Java and C++ side use a lot of threads (polling, loading, calculating). Most of the threads are meant to run continuously in parallel with the rest of the app (for example to stream music from MP3). Some threads are meant to be run once (like submitting a large file to a cloud service).

Now the question is what's the best way to handle native threads during onPause/onResume events? Is it okay to just leave as they are, and possibly call sleep(x) on them? Or should they be killed (and their states stored somehow) and re-created during onResume?

Comment: It's bad for the device if the threads continue to run while your app is in the background (it can hamper the performance of other apps and drain the battery), and it's bad for you if the threads were doing "permanent" work like uploading a file because the app can be killed at any time.  There's no difference between "managed" threads and "native" threads in this regard; the VM does not collaborate with the app framework to stop your Java-language code from running while the app is paused.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can't actually "kill" (cancel) a pthread in Android.  So likely your option is to indicate to them that you wish them to stop, not give them work, leave them waiting on something blocking, etc, or have them terminate.  I don't think a thread waiting in a blocking call is particularly heavy, unless it has allocated an unusually large amount of memory which it could perhaps explicitly free if it were going to shut itself down.